# Viewing SSRS Report in Report Manager With Keyboard Only

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, reportmanager

We have a requirement where user have no pointing device, user must use SSRS report manager to view report with keyboard only, but I am unable to select values for a multi-valued parameters, I managed to pop up the list, but when I press tab, focus moves to next parameters instead of going into the list of multi-valued parameter.

I tried many different keyboard combinations, but none is working. Also checked for any option on parameter itself, but did not find anything.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a question you dont hear every day - I presume this is for accessability reasons?

I think you are at the mercy of your browser here.  The following seems to work on IE9:

- tab to the drop-down arrow and press space to drop down the list
- press shift-tab then tab - this should get you to the (Select All) row.
- use tab and shift-tab to scroll up and down the list
- use space to select / unselect each row in the list
- use tab or shift-tab to scroll off the end of the list
- note your focus is now on the Show/Hide Parameters button (odd).  You can tab or shift-tab from there to the next parameter.

Comment: This solution works when you have many values in parameters, but when we have few values, like 2 - 3 values, this does not work.

Comment: I mean that if the loaded parameter has several values in it, it focus Into the listbox, but when it has only 2 or 3 values, it does not go into the listbox.